# add class to the parent of text if the text is عربي(arabic) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code

```
var arabic = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;
var string = 'عربية‎'; // some Arabic string from Wikipedia

alert(arabic.test(string)); // displays true
```

this code detect if the text is arabic.

please can i use this with the jQuery, i want to add class to the parent of text if the text is arabic ?

Example:
    `<div>text</div>` if text is arabic `<div class="arabicText">text</div>`

Thank You for your helps

Comment: `$(your-text-element-selector).parent().addClass(your-class)`;

Comment: You could try to use the jQuery `:contains` selector, however I don't know if it supports regex. Docs: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: If your text is straight into a `div` and that's the element you want to add the `class`, `$(your-text-element-selector).addClass(your-class)`;

Comment: Have a good read: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Well, since you asked nicely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div id="mydiv">بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم</div>
```

if you have that :

```
if(arabic.test($('#mydiv').html())){

   $('#mydiv').addClass('arabicText') 
}
```

You will get

```
<div id="mydiv" class="arabicText">بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم</div>
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/Q6rZr/)